# How to detect verion of HS 6 digits code?

Tags: macroeconomics, international-trade, statistics, data

I have trade data with HS 6 digits codes. However, I don't know which version of HS is used.
I wonder if there is any practice in statistics to detect which version (HS1, HS2...HS5) is used?

Comment: I'm like 99% sure, but feel like I should still check: you are talking about the shotgun projectile propellant Hodgdon HS, right?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonized_System